# Check Subdomain using whois

Tags: php, mysql, subdomain, whois

I'm trying to add subdomain to the list of my whois file. So my website visitors can check availability of the subdomains they want.

Is there anyway to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  whois is just for domains.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the answer. Do you have an advice for me what i'd better to do?

Comment: Maybe track them on your website itself.

Comment: I'm sorry but i don't really understand the rules of this forum. can you tell me what do you mean?

Comment: @KamaludinKhoir Click the outlined checkbox on the left side of this post to mark it as accepted.